# Listing available questions/commands for MS teams chatbot / javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

For a chatbot project on MS Teams, I want to list available questions above/below message box based on the words that's been written to message box. I'm using Javascript/node.js for general chatbot configuration, specifically Microsoft Bot Framework SDK.

What I try to do is, I want user to be informed about available questions. And I want it to be done BEFORE the message is sent.

1. User will start to write the question on Teams (for test, in botframework emulator)
2. At the same time questions that matched with these words will be shown like a dropdown menu.
3. User will be able to select from these questions.

Below is an example for this but it's using adaptive cards contrary to my case

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These suggestions are defined in the "bots" section app manifest.json file under "commandLists":

```
"bots": [
{
  "botId": "<YOUR BOT ID>",
  "scopes": [
    "personal"
  ],
  "commandLists": [
    {
      "commands": [
        {
          "title": "Welcome",
          "description": "Resend welcome card of this bot"
        }
      ],
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "isNotificationOnly": false,
  "supportsCalling": false,
  "supportsVideo": false,
  "supportsFiles": true
}
]
```